# how do i perform linear regression on dataframe in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, regression, jupyter, glm

`

```
M = Matrix(df[:, 2:3])
X = zeros(size(M[:, 1], 1), 2)
X[:, 1] = M[:, 1] # X is the reference data
X[:, 2] .= 1.0
Y = M[:, 2] # Y is the non reference
coeff_pred = X \ Y # this gives you the slope and the intercept
```

`MethodError: no method matching oneunit(::Type{Any})`

this is my dataframe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wiuJ.png)

I think it has to do with the matrix being of type any but when i try parse the columns as int64 or float64 i get a different error

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
M = Matrix{Float64}(df[:, 2:3])
```

If this errors it means that your data frame contains non-numeric values and you first need to clean them.

Answer (score 1):

Bogumil's answer is likely correct, consider:

```
julia> Any[1 2; 3 4] \ Any[5, 6]
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching oneunit(::Type{Any})
```

versus

```
julia> [1 2; 3 4] \ [5, 6]
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 -3.9999999999999987
  4.499999999999999
```

I will add one thing: when I see people with DataFrames consisting of only `Any` typed columns for no apparent reason, it turns out in 90% of all cases they have been reading in an Excel file using the `XLSX.jl` and not using the `infer_eltypes` keyword. From [the docs](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/api/#XLSX.readtable):

> Use `infer_eltypes=true` to get data as a `Vector{Any}` of typed vectors. The default value is `infer_eltypes=false`.